# Error : popap html con Jquery

Tags: jquery, html5, asp.net, jquery-ui, knockoutjs

Tengo un error de llamar a un popap utilizando Jquery:

**1. Botón Código HTML**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnAddCentrocosto" value="AddCentrocosto" onclick="$parent.openAddCentrocosto">Agregar Centro Costos</button>
```

**2. Popap HTML**

```
<div class="panel-heading" id="dialogAddCentrocosto" title="Centro de Costos..."> 
        <table>          
            <tr>
                <td><label>Costo : </label></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="nCosto" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Observaciones : </label></td>
                <td><textarea rows="5" id="strObservacionDistribucion"   class="form-control" name="strObservacionDistribucion"></textarea></td>    
            </tr>

        </table>
</div>
```

**3. Jquery**

```
self.openAddCentrocosto = function () {
            tr = jQuery('#btnAddCentrocosto').parent().parent();
            jQuery('#Distribucion').val(jQuery('td[data-bind="text: Distribucion"]', tr).text()); 
            jQuery('#nCosto').val('');
            jQuery('#nImpuestoDistribucion').val('18');
            //jQuery('#nTotalDistribucion').val('');
            jQuery('#dialogAddCentrocosto').dialog('open');
        }
```

**4. Mensaje de error**
Al hacer click sobre el boton me deberia levantar el popap, pero no se realiza y me muestra el siguiente mensaje de error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $parent is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick
```

Por favor si alguien me puede ayudar con este error, muchas gracias.

Comment: intenta poner onclick="openAddCentrocosto();"

Comment: #juliocpiro, aun no reconoce la función.

Comment: esta linea esta incompleta **jQuery('#Distribucion').val(jQuery('td[data-bind="text:**, comentala

Comment: #juliocpiro, se ha actualizado la línea y aún no reconoce la función.

Comment: he punblicado la respuesta, inicialice el dialog, revisalo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes una linea error, llama a la funcion sin *$parent* y asegurate de  inicializar el `dialog`:

```
jQuery('#Distribucion').val(jQuery('td[data-bind="text: //comentala
```

**Solucion**

```html
<html>
<head>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>
 <script>
  $(function(){
   jQuery('#dialogAddCentrocosto').dialog({autoOpen: false,width:'auto'});
   
   self.openAddCentrocosto = function () {
             tr = jQuery('#btnAddCentrocosto').parent().parent();
             //jQuery('#Distribucion').val(jQuery('td[data-bind="text: 
             jQuery('#nCosto').val('');
             jQuery('#nImpuestoDistribucion').val('18');
             //jQuery('#nTotalDistribucion').val('');
             jQuery('#dialogAddCentrocosto').dialog('open');
         }
        });  
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnAddCentrocosto" value="AddCentrocosto" onclick="openAddCentrocosto()">Agregar Centro Costos</button>
 <div class="panel-heading" id="dialogAddCentrocosto" title="Centro de Costos..."> 
        <table>          
            <tr>
                <td><label>Costo : </label></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="nCosto" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Observaciones : </label></td>
                <td><textarea rows="5" id="strObservacionDistribucion"   class="form-control" name="strObservacionDistribucion"></textarea></td>    
            </tr>

        </table>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: #juliocpiro, funciono correctamente, muchas gracias.